# Can shiny sliderInput show nothing - i.e. be like screen brightness slider in cell phones?

Tags: r, shiny

Can shiny sliderInput  show nothing - i.e. be like screen brightness slider in cell phones?
[image]

E.g. like in this code, but not show min, max and value?

```
sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 100, value = 80
  )
```

Comment: IVIM, is there something holding you back from accepting ismirsehregal's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via CSS:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .irs-grid, .irs-grid-text, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-single {
        visibility: hidden !important;
      }"))
  ),
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "test",
    label = "",
    min = 0L,
    max = 100L,
    value = 80L
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

As per @r2evans comment, the following modifies only a single `sliderInput`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .test1class .irs-grid, .test1class .irs-grid-text, .test1class .irs-min, .test1class .irs-max, .test1class .irs-single {
        visibility: hidden !important;
      }"))
  ),
  tagAppendAttributes(
    sliderInput(
      inputId = "test1",
      label = "",
      min = 0L,
      max = 100L,
      value = 80L
    ), class = "test1class"),
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "test2",
    label = "",
    min = 0L,
    max = 100L,
    value = 80L
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Nice approach! How hard is it to limit this to a single (of multiple) slider?

Comment: Self-answer: not too hard. Wrap the desired input with `tags$span(class="QUUX", sliderInput(...))`, then change the style preamble to `.QUUX .irs-grid, .QUUX .irs-grid-text, .QUUX .irs-min, .QUUX .irs-max, .QUUX .irs-single`. Using this, the style is restricted to just the one input. Thanks @ismirsehregal

Comment: @r2evans saw your comment just now. If you don't mind I'll add your self-answer to my above post when I'm back at a Dektop-PC. Cheers

Comment: Feel free to add it, glad you think it's worthy :-)